# Batch file to detect only part of a filename

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

I need a snippet of a batch file that can detect part of a filename, then rename it.
Note that the numbers after the filename change randomly but "file" is always the same.

Example:

filename: file143424

There will always be only one file that needs to be renamed in the folder. The script will delete older versions of the file. For instance, I put a first file inside the folder and the script in there too. I then run the script, which renames it to just file. Then if I put a new file in, the script, when run again, will recognize it from the "file" prefix and rename it to file after deleting the old one.

Comment: You need to tell us what you tried. You admit as much by saying "I will add more details if necessary." Why not put in all the details first, to make it easier on those who are trying to help you? As of this point you have two answers, both good, but both incomplete, because you haven't told us what the result of the operation should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excuse me. Your question is incomplete, I think. You want to rename "file134342" to what?

In your comment you said: rename it to just "file", but this works only if there is just *one* file with that name. Anyway, here it is:

```
for %%f in (file*) do ren %%f file
```

If this is not what you want, then give us more details (you showld always give full details from the very beginning).

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the first four characters that way:

```
if "%filename:~0,4%"=="file" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Aacini's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10971355/297408) should work fine in your case. But you could do very well without a `for` loop, a single `REN` (`RENAME`) command would be enough:

```
RENAME file* file
```