# A12345678.textornumbers.textornumbers.txt to A12345678.txt

Tags: batch-file

I try to create a batch file to automaticaly rename the files contained in a folder, from this structure: A12345678.textornumbers.textornumbers.txt to a more simple one: A12345678.txt

I tried something like this:

```
@echo off
ECHO Renaming files
Pause
:begin
ECHO Renaming txt files
for /r %%x in (A*.*.*.txt) do (REN "%%x" A*.txt)
ECHO Renaming finished
:end
pause
done
```

It does not return any error, but it does nothing...

**EDITED:**

Ok, the problem could be seen in other way: i want to rename the file remaining the first 9 characters and the extension.

I saw a similar question here:
[Deleting characters from filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969981/batch-file-to-detect-only-part-of-a-filename)

I modified and adjusted to my case to have this:

```
@echo off
ECHO Renaming files
Pause
:begin
REM setlocal enabledelayedexpansion (the result is the same with and without this line)
set X=9
ECHO Renaming files
for /r %%f in (*.txt) do if %%f neq %~nx0 (
    set "filename=%%~nf"
    set "filename=!filename:~%X%,-%X%!"
    ren "%%f" "!filename!%%~xf")
ECHO Done
ECHO Processing finished
:end
pause
done
```

But the result is this:

> Blockquote
>   !filename!.txt

This is for the first image in the directoy, and errors (Such file already exist) for the others.

**EDITED 2:**

Thanks to the replies and other information i found on internet, here is the solution i had: to remove the last characters of the filename, because i want to remain ever the first 9 characters:

```
@echo off
ECHO renaming files
ECHO.
Pause
:begin

set ext=QUB
set num=17
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b /a *.%ext%') do call :lab %%f
ECHO Done
pause
Exit

:lab
set original=
set original=%*
set newname=
call set newname=%%original:.%ext%=%%
call set newname=%%newname:~0,-%num%%%.%ext%
if "%newname%"==".%ext%" (goto :eof)
ren "%original%" "%newname%"
ECHO %newname%
goto :eof
```

This is not my code, but the solution i used from others ([by Carlitos.dll](http://foro.elhacker.net/scripting/iquestbat_que_borre_4_ultimos_caracteres_de_los_nombres_de_varios_archivos-t219645.15.html)). I hope it could help to others with similar problems. Thanks for your ideas and help!

Comment: I think the `ren` command just isn't smart enough to guess your intention.

Comment: @Joey - But REN is flexible enough to get the job done :-) See my answer.

Comment: See my revised answer for a much simpler solution to your revised question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script does do something, but nothing useful - It renames each file to it's original name :-(

It all has to do with the rules for how REN works with wildcards. I had never seen any proper explanation of how REN works posted *anywhere*. So a few weeks ago I did extensive experiments and developed a set of rules that explain all the behavior I observed.

You can find my results at [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards) on the StackExchange SuperUser site.

Your problem is easily solved by replacing `*` with many `?` in your target name. Just make sure the number of `?` is greater than or equal to the max leading name length that you will process. You also don't need to specify the leading `A` if you are not changing the value.

```
for /r %%x in (A*.*.*.txt) do ren "%%x" ?????????????????????.txt
```

The above must iterate each file. It may be a bit faster to iterate the folders only, though I haven't tested

```
for /r /d %%x in (.) do ren "%%x\A*.*.*.txt" ?????????????????????.txt
```

It is also possible to parse the name with FOR /F so that you don't have to worry about the number of `?`.

```
for /r %%x in (a*.*.*.txt) do (
  for /f "delims=." %%n in ("%%~nx") do ren "%%x" "%%n.txt"
)
```

**EDIT based on revised question**

To simply preserve up to the 1st 9 characters and the `.txt` extension, the solution is even easier, just use 9 `?`:

```
for /r /d %%x in (.) do ren "%%x\*.txt" ?????????.txt
```

If you want to rename all files, not just `.txt` files, then

```
for /r %%F in (*) do ren "%%F" "?????????%%~xF"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this:

```
for %%x in (*.textornumbers.txt) do (
  set nam=%%x
  if "!nam!" neq "!nam:.textornumbers=!" ren %%x !nam:.textornumbers=!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `~`-modifiers, you could do the following:

1. Take just the name from the original full path and name (& extension):

   ```
   FOR /R %%A IN (A*.*.*.txt) DO (
     ... %%~nA ...
   )
   ```

   That will turn a `D:\path\A*.*.*.txt` to just an `A*.*.*`.

   Take just the name from the result of #1:

   ```
   FOR /R %%A IN (A*.*.*.txt) DO (
     FOR %%B IN ("%%~nA") DO (
       ... %%~nB ...
     )
   )
   ```

   That will leave you with `A*.*`.

   Take just the name from #2:

   ```
   FOR /R %%A IN (A*.*.*.txt) DO (
     FOR %%B IN ("%%~nA") DO (
       FOR %%C IN ("%%~nB") DO (
         ... %%~nC ...
       )
     )
   )
   ```

   which will give you `A*`.

   Extract the extension from the original name and concatenate it with #3. That will be the final name, `A*.txt`, which you can now supply to the `RENAME` command:

   ```
   FOR /R %%A IN (A*.*.*.txt) DO (
     FOR %%B IN ("%%~nA") DO (
       FOR %%C IN ("%%~nB") DO (
         RENAME "%%A" "%%~nC%%~xA"
       )
     )
   )
   ```